# How to calculate partial derivatives of error function with respect to values in matrix

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, gradient-descent, derivative

I am building a project that is a basic neural network that takes in a 2x2 image with the goal to classify the image as either a forward slash (1-class) or back slash (0-class) shape. The data for the input is a flat numpy array. 1 represents a black pixel 0 represents a white pixel.

0-class: [1, 0, 0, 1]

1-class: [0, 1, 1, 0]

If I start my filter as a random 4x1 matrix, how can I use gradient descent to come to either perfect matrix [1,-1,-1,1] or [-1,1,1,-1] to classify the datapoints.

Side note: Even when multiplied with the "perfect" answer matrix then summed, the label output would be -2 and 2. Would my data labels need to be -2 and 2? What if I want my classes labeled as 0 and 1?

Comment: Who gives you those "perfect matrix"? If you directly use the multiplication result as the class label, you would have a hard time bounding them between [0, 1]. Consider using a [sigmoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) function

Comment: Also, try unrolling the operations. How do human compute matrix multiplication? If you write it out I think the solution is pretty clear